# Unnest list of lists of data frames, containing NAs

Tags: r

I have a list of nested data, containing lists with two data frames each looking like this:

```
mylist <- list(
              list(
                p = data.frame(
                    id = "01",
                    stringsAsFactors = F
                    ),
                c = data.frame(
                    text = c("one", "two"),
                    from = c("A", "B"),
                    stringsAsFactors = F
                    )
                  ),
               list(
                  p = data.frame(
                    id = "02",
                    stringsAsFactors = F
                    ),
                  c = data.frame(
                    text = c("three", "four", "five"),
                    from = c("C", "D", "E"),
                    stringsAsFactors = F
                    )
                   ),
                list(
                    p = data.frame(
                      id = "03",
                      stringsAsFactors = F
                      ),
                    c = data.frame(
                      text = logical(0),
                      from = logical(0)
                      )
                    )
                  )
```

I want to flatten this list into a dataframe, with one row per observation from the "c" data frames, a colum that indicates the "id" of the level above stored in the "p" dataframes, and non-observations filled with NAs. The result should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
            p.id = c("01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "03"),
            c.text = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", NA),
            c.from = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", NA)
)

# 
# p.id c.text c.from
# 01    one      A
# 01    two      B
# 02  three      C
# 02   four      D
# 02   five      E
# 03   <NA>   <NA>
```

as.data.frame() provides a very simple solution that comes very close to the desired result, but breaks when there are 0 observations in the "c" data frame.

```
mylist[[1]] %>% as.data.frame()
mylist[[3]] %>% as.data.frame()
```

I am aware that are similar questions on stackoverflow - but I read several threads closely, have tried different things from bind_rows(), to jsonlite::flatten(), tidr::unnest(), or data.table::rbindlist() - but have not make it work.

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a helper function to combine `p` and `c`:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  a <- x[[1]]
  b <- x[[2]]
  if (nrow(b) == 0) b[1, ] <- NA
  return(cbind(a, b))
}
```

Then I run the helper function on each element and bind the rows:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, foo))
```

The result:

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, foo))
  id  text from
1 01   one    A
2 01   two    B
3 02 three    C
4 02  four    D
5 02  five    E
6 03  <NA> <NA>
```

P.S. The same result using the R base pipe:

```
lapply(mylist, foo) |> do.call(what = rbind)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(mylist, ~as_tibble(.)) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_longer(value)
```

Which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   name value$p$id $c$text $$from
  <int> <chr>      <chr>   <chr> 
1     1 01         one     A     
2     1 01         two     B     
3     2 02         three   C     
4     2 02         four    D     
5     2 02         five    E     
6     3 NA         NA      NA
```